# How do I resequence dropdown list controls like the NetFlix queue from the client side (Javascript)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, drop-down-menu

We have a series of drop down controls that determine the sort order of columns.  The problem we are having is when the user selects a column as the 2nd column the other dropdown lists need to have their values changed so that there is only one "2nd".

1. Column A       [1]
2. Column B       [2]
3. Column C       [3]
4. Column D       [4]
5. Column E       [5]

In the list above, when you change Column D to [2], Column B becomes [3], C becomes [4], etc.  I can manage it on the server side but I was wondering if anybody had some clues how to do this on the client side with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Javascript toolkits like [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) for client side reordering.

You add your elements as "[Sortables](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/sortable)" and code your own callbacks to execute when the items are dragged, then dropped -- such as sending an asynchronous request to the server to persist the new order.

Here is a [full tutorial](http://zenofshen.com/posts/ajax-sortable-lists-tutorial) on creating sortable lists with Scriptaculous and PHP. For ASP, the client side code will be slightly different, but the process will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

On a note on JavaScript frameworks; I highly recommend [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).